# hide certain fields of a compound datatype from being written to (or read back from) hdf5 file

Tags: c++, c, hdf5

I was expecting that by not inserting a field into memory_type, I could avoid outputting that field to disk. However, the following test program shows that this is not the case. Even if I did not insert the field `c`, everything is written and everything is read back as well. *(Although the sample code is given in C++, any solution using the C API of [hdf5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/compound.html) is equally appreciated!)*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
#include "H5Cpp.h"
using namespace H5;


const H5std_string FILE_NAME( "test_compound2.hdf5" );
const H5std_string DATASET_NAME( "data" );
const int   LENGTH = 5;
const int   RANK = 1;

#define ShowField(s,f){\
cout << endl<<"Field "<<#f<<" : " << endl; \
  for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)\
    cout<<s[i].f<<" ";\
      cout<<endl;\
        }

int main(void)
{

  struct s_t
  {
    int    a;
    float  b;
    int c;
    };
  CompType mtype( sizeof(s_t) );
  /*only insert a,b, do not insert c*/
  mtype.insertMember( "a", HOFFSET(s_t, a), PredType::NATIVE_INT);
  mtype.insertMember( "b", HOFFSET(s_t, b), PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);
  /*note field c is not inserted!*/

  hsize_t dim[] = {LENGTH};
  vector <s_t> datain(LENGTH);
  for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)/* init data*/
  {
    datain[i].a=i;
    datain[i].b=i*i;
    datain[i].c=-i;
    }
  cout<<"==========Data initialized=============\n";
  ShowField(datain, a);
  ShowField(datain, b);
  ShowField(datain, c);

  /*write to file*/
  {
    DataSpace space( RANK, dim );
    H5File file( FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC );
    DataSet dset(file.createDataSet(DATASET_NAME, mtype, space));
    dset.write( datain.data(), mtype );
    }

  /*read back*/
  H5File file( FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY );
  DataSet dset(file.openDataSet( DATASET_NAME ));
  vector <s_t> dataout(LENGTH);

  dset.read( dataout.data(), mtype );

  cout<<"\n===========Data Read==========\n";
  ShowField(dataout,a);
  ShowField(dataout,b);
  ShowField(dataout,c); 

  return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows. Note field `c` is read back correctly, though not inserted in `memtype`!

```
  ==========Data initialized=============

  Field a : 
  0 1 2 3 4 

  Field b : 
  0 1 4 9 16 

  Field c : 
  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 

  ===========Data Read==========

  Field a : 
  0 1 2 3 4 

  Field b : 
  0 1 4 9 16 

  Field c : 
  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
```

I guess it has to do with the size of memtype. I tried pack() to reduce the size but the data interpretation then went wrong.

Defining a new struct containing only these wanted fields is not optimal, since it would require copying the data to the new struct or back, while my application involves huge amounts of data. What I try to hide is actually a vector field, which I write out separately as an array of variable-length arrays. Currently although I have omitted the vector field in memtype, it is still written and then read back as well, which corrupts the memory (the reading automatically fills the size and memory pointer of the vectors with their written values, which are not valid pointers anymore).

So is there a way that I can truly hide a particular field from being written as well as from being read back, without having to define a new temporary class?

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ questions!

Comment: The question is mainly concerned about hdf5, which has both C and C++ APIs (the C++ version is mostly wrapped C routines). I can post a C version as well... I have emphasized this in the end of the first paragraph, in case someone remove my C tag... Please can I get the C tag back, for a wider audience? I feel there are probably more people using C-hdf5 than C++-hdf5.

Comment: Anyone familiar with the C and C++ HDF5 libraries knows that they are almost interchangeable so both tags are justified here.

Answer (score 1):

After digging the documentation and testing, I found the solution below. The key is to specify a different storage model from the memory model when saving. This storage type is a compact version of `mtype` that removes the un-used fields. The `pack()` function can serve to achieve this:

```
CompType mtype_disk;
mtype_disk.copy(mtype);
mtype_disk.pack()
```

Now the size of `mtype_disk` should be smaller than `mtype`, since the unused fields (and possibly some padding) are removed. Creating the dataset with `mtype_disk`, instead of `mtype`, will make sure that only the fields explicitly inserted into `mtype` (and hence `mtype_disk` as well) will get written.

```
DataSet dset(file.createDataSet(DATASET_NAME, mtype_disk, space));
dset.write(datain.data(), mtype);
```

The dataset creation step is the only place where `mtype_disk` is needed. When reading the data back, `mtype` should be used as before to describe the memory layout.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. For reference, [this example](https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_6/C/H5T/h5ex_t_cpxcmpd.c) is useful.

Comment: Thank you Simon. I got the hints from the [user's guide](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/11_Datatypes.html#Dtransfer) which mentioned the concept briefly.